# CSS drop shadow not showing on iPhone…?

Tags: iphone, css, button, safari

I have a drop shadow on the animated buttons on my [website](http://v3.edharrisondesign.com/about/) which works fine across all browsers but it doesn't seem to be showing up on the iPhone... strange because it was showing a couple of days ago. Not exactly sure what I've changed to prevent it working.

Any pointers to what I've done wrong would be much appreciated!

Comment: I only see box-shadow and not -webkit-box-shadow. Am I missing something? Works on my iphone running ios5 and current mobile safari

Comment: Cheers Alex no idea how I missed that!

Comment: No worries. Css3 throw me sometimes cuz sometimes it appears to work until you find that one edge case you forgot to code for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Older versions of safari need the -webkit-box-shadow since box-shadow was not fully supported. However it does work on the newest mobile safari

Answer (score 0):

You will also run into problems with IE8 and IE7 using box-shadow. If I could recommend something (and I tend to do this), it is to make some images and use that as the background for those. It is a little bit of work but that is the safest route.

Comment: Yeah thats a great idea. So just offset a background image by 1px 5 times in a similar way right?

Comment: Yup! That is pretty much all you have to do! Sorry for the late response. If this works out for you and if you don't mind, can you mark this as an answer so if others run into this, they know what they might want to consider?